# Using a C# variable as a table element

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

What I have is this:

```
<table>
   <tr bgcolor="#007ACC" style="color:White">
      <td width="145">Account Group</td>
      <td width="80"></td>
      <td width="10">Active</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    ·
    ·
   </tr>
</table>
```

What I need to do is make it so "Account Group" can be changed based on a user's treeview selection.  i.e., if the user selects a Child node, I need to change that to "Account Number".

Is it possible to change a table element on-the-fly like that?  If so, how would I do this?

Comment: You only need to do this for a single `td` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a label in `<td>` to display text, so that you can change them based on label `id`

```
 <td width="145">
    <asp:Label Text="Account Group" ID="lblUserContent" runat="server" />
 </td>
```

As per `treeview  selection changes` you can change the text by using following code:

```
if(your condition)
   lblUserContent.Text="Account Number"
else
   lblUserContent.Text="Account Group"
```

Comment: Frickin' genius.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this will depend on how you're using your treeview, but here's a quick way to output the value of a C# variable into your table:

```
<table>
  <tr bgcolor="#007ACC" style="color:White">
    <td width="145"><%# Eval("MyCSharpVariable") %></td>
    <td width="80"></td>
    <td width="10">Active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  ·
  ·
  </tr>
</table>
```